# EFI partition severely damaged, can't boot to any OS on hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I have installed OpenSUSE Tumbleweed before installing Windows 10 (both installed from a USB stick on UEFI mode).
OpenSUSE didn't recognize the new OS and didn't place it in it's own grub menu, and after installing Windows, it overwrote the boot order and then I had to open Boot Options whenever I wanted to use OpenSUSE.
In an attempt to add Windows to OpenSUSE's grub menu, i ended up locking myself out of the system after changing grub's EFI mode to regular grub (I know, my fault for doing things the wrong way and not researching first).
At first glance I thought that wouldn't affect Windows in any way and I could boot into it normally, but instead this went so far that my BIOS didn't find any place to boot and threw me a `No bootable hard drives found` error.
I discovered that booting from USB sticks still worked and from there I tried what I could to restore my system. I tried:

- Reinstalling grub
- Using `boot-rescue`
- Reformatting the ESP partition and restoring a backup
- Deleting every partition in my hard disk and installing KDE neon
- Reformatting the ESP partition, leaving it clean and installing KDE neon
- Reinstalling Windows (files are installed but it can't boot after a restart)
- Using Rescatux to repair grub
- Using `bootrec /fixboot` and `bcdboot C:\Windows /s (efi):` while on Windows' "Repair your computer" feature
- Using Windows' Startup Repair feature
- Trying to boot from grub command line (through a live OS' EFI grub menu)

But nothing appeared to work or even progress towards fixing my problem.
Here is the `boot-rescue` pastebin, and although it says "Boot successfully repaired", it didn't do a thing.
https://pastebin.com/12cDGmMH

Currently my only means of booting are:

- Linux Mint Tina (on dvd disc)
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (on dvd disc)
- Windows 10 Pro (on usb)

I am able to create bootable usb drives using another computer. I am not able to burn discs.
Is there any way I can get this machine back running?

Comment: Did you reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode?  Since drive is gpt it must be UEFI, unless you converted from MBR to gpt after install. But these are typical Windows partitions: BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations You have no UEFI boot entries and Microsoft boot in ESP. But also BIOS in MBR.

Comment: Yes, I've installed Windows in UEFI mode, and my boot mode has Legacy OPROM support as well as the UEFI entries.

Comment: You show a BIOS/Legacy boot - syslinux in MBR. Do not try to boot in BIOS mode and that will not be used. It will only give errors. You are not showing an UEFI boot entries and only Windows UEFI boot files in ESP. You may need full Windows repairs and then turn off Windows fast start up as there are multiple issues on mounting it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
Report is not showing any other Linux bootable files. kernels, fstab etc.